# Wordpress theme option - HTML from textarea (sort of working)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, textarea

I have some issues with getting HTML tags from my textarea theme option in Wordpress.

If I make a new style and div/class within the option, then I can style my text and so on. But "normal" HTML tags are not working (except for `<br>`, it's the only one working) such as `<b>` and `<sup>`.

I'm still fairly new at Wordpress and PHP in general, and I just can't seem to find the mistake. There are no errors in the console, and the option code is working in another theme I have, with default HTML tags.

Current style (Not sure how relevant this is):

```css
#footer-body{
    width: 980px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000; 
    position: relative;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 5%, #1e5799 100%);
}
#footer-text{
    width: 780px;
    height: 49px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Current code:

```html
<div id="footer-body"><br>
    <div id="footer-text">
         <?php 
             $footer_text = stripslashes (get_option ('qlixtheme_footer_text')); ?>
         <?php echo $footer_text; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly does _"normal" HTML tags are not working_ mean? Are they invisible, or don't they get their styles applied? In the last case, I'd check if there aren't any "reset" styles in effect. Look for `*` as a selector.

Comment: Yes they're not getting their styles. Unless I make a new div wihtin the theme option. I have another option for the background color of the "footer-body" but that can't be it?

Comment: I don't think so. You don't have a link to the site, so I can have a look?

Comment: Yes ofcource http://powernordic.eu/ - It's the footer text currently saying "hej hej This text contains superscript text."

Comment: The problem is in http://powernordic.eu/wp-content/themes/qlixtheme/style.css in line 11, where a whole slew of elements get reset to `font:inherit` (switching bold off), `vertical-align:baseline` (switching superscript off) etc.

Comment: Oh wow... Now I feel so dumb :( Thanks a lot!